# transpose of data in a comma separated row

Tags: python, bash

I have a file, which has data in one column and 200 rows (200*1).

I want to get this data in a single row with comma separated.

Example File

```
Paul
Pammy
Jacob
Robin
```

Output

```
Paul, Pammy, Jacob, Robin
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using `sed`:

```
sed ':a;{N;s/\n/, /};ba' INPUT_FILE
```

#### Explanation:

I am no expert on `sed`, but this is what the above one-liner means:

1. `:a`

   `:label` command creates a named label `a`. This when used with `ba` branches to the label. This is useful for creating loops and escaping to the end of the script to print the current pattern space.
2. `N`

   `N` just appends the next line to the pattern space with `\n`.
3. `s/\n/, /`

   Since the new line has been appended to the pattern space with a `\n`, we use this substitution to replace the `\n` with a `,` and `space` as per the requirements of OP.

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
Paul
Pammy
Jacob
Robin

[jaypal:~/Temp] sed ':a;{N;s/\n/, /};ba' file
Paul, Pammy, Jacob, Robin
```

Comment: Looks good from here, but any chance you could explain a little better? I don't even get it, and the last thing this world needs is another cryptic `sed` command. :P

Comment: Awesome! I wasn't even aware of the label/branch functionality.

Comment: There are two methods of `branching (looping)` in `sed`. One is through `b command` and the other is through `t command`. The difference is, with `t command`, you can do `conditional branching`. The `t command` branches to a `label` only if a previous `s command` modified the pattern space, else it branches to the end of the script. It's crazy, that's why I have this love hate relationship with `sed`. :)

Comment: @DanFego Here is the [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands).

Comment: Glad to hear your facing your deamons! This does the same job if I might offer an ameliorated version `sed ':a;$!{N;ba};y/\n/,/'`

Comment: @DanFego Let me introduce you to potong - The **`God of sed`**. I was surprised to not see your reply, potong. :)

Answer (score 4):

## `awk`:

```
$ awk -v ORS=, 1 file.txt | sed 's/,$/\n/'
Paul,Pammy,Jacob,Robin
```

- **`-v ORS=,`** set output record separated by `,`
- **`1`** TRUE, so print every record
- **`sed 's/,$/\n/'`** remove ending `,`

## `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '1h;1!H;${g;s/\n/,/gp}' file.txt
Paul,Pammy,Jacob,Robin
```

- **`-n`** suppress output
- **`1h`** put first line to holding-space
- **`1!H`** append second~last lines to holding-space
- **`${...}`** do ... against last line
- **`g`** get all from holding-space
- **`s/\n/,/g`** replace `\n` with `,`
- **`p`** print out

## `tr:`

```
$ tr '\n' ',' <file.txt | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

Comment: We can remove the `cat` from `tr` version and simply do `tr '\n' ',' < file.txt | sed 's/,$/\n/'`

Comment: @kev with builtin vars like ORS, you can forgo the `-v` if you put them at the end like so: `awk 1 ORS=, file.txt`

Comment: @SiegeX Yep, Thats a nice way of doing it … Though I have to admit, I have never really followed that convention, always ended up using `-v`. Guess I should start practicing it in this manner more often … looks much cleaner. :)

Answer (score 2):

this seems to work, uses 'tr' command on unix/linux

```
tr '\n', ',' < yourfile
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python

```
  ', '.join(open("yourinputfile").read().splitlines())
```

In Bash

```
 cat test.txt|xargs -I {} echo -n {},
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
perl -pe 'chomp; print ", " if $. - 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
paste -d, -s file.txt
```